# WIX Complex Condition

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

Is that possible WIX Condition to have nested if else?

```
<Condition>
     <Condition>
     </Condition>
</Condition>
```

Comment: What sort of nested condition are you interested in creating?  Logically, a nested condition maps to a boolean `and` operation, and there might be an alternative way to do that.  The only requirement to explicitly nest (that couldn't be replaced with an AND) would be if you want short-circuit resolution (so the second operation/check isn't performed if the first evaluates to false).  Not sure how important that is in this context.  Some more information would increase the quality of this question...

Comment: It seems you're trying to do the simple things in a complex way. :) A combination of separate conditions and logical operators will do the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use OR or AND like this:

```
<Condition Message="Test Message">
    Installed OR MYPROPERTY
</Condition>
```

Comment: But above always show the message if it is false, I want to set ignore if it is false.

Comment: Then split it in two separate conditions. 'Ignore' means the condition is passed and the installation continues, hence if you want to ignore if it's false, invert it and put into a separate condition.